# npm command not found in zsh but found in bash

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I installed `npm` with `nvm` and the first time it went all great, now I tried to check npm version on Mac terminal an it shows:

```
% npm --version
zsh: command not found: npm
```

But using VSCode terminal with bash, with same command, shows:

```
npm --version
6.14.12
```

Is there a chance I installed the wrong way `npm` or `nvm`? Or is this a way I can tell Mac terminal to use bash instead of zsh?

Comment: Will you please send the output of `which npm` in **bash**?

Comment: Like the above comment said, try to figure out which version of npm is being run on VSCode. It will say something like ```/usr/bin/npm```. If you type this path into your zsh terminal I would expect it to run properly.

Comment: `type -a npm` would be preferable to `which`

Comment: @user17242583 `which npm` shows the following: 
`/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/npm`

Comment: @glennjackman `type -a npm` shows 
`npm is /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/npm`

Comment: @squidwardsface yes, I tried changing the commands shell path of Mac terminal but still showing command not found, maybe I typed it wrong. Knowing what the `which` command show with `npm` in comments above what should I type for shell path?

Comment: Then add `$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin` to your zsh PATH.

Comment: Should I add that line to `zshrc` file even if that file doesn't exist or should I create the file and add the PATH? I'm worried that that might not work properly.

Comment: @glennjackman I added that line to `~/.zshrc` file then I restarted my terminal and showed `permission denied/Users/myuser/.zshrc:1: permission denied: /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue first by executing `echo $PATH` in both `bash` and `zsh` the result was:

`bash`: `/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

`zsh`: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Both paths have `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

But only `bash` has this: `/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:`

So I needed to add that missing path to zhs path, since I didn't have a `.zshrc` file I needed to do:

`echo 'PATH="~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

After that I do `reset` on terminal and verify again with `echo $PATH` that I have the same path on both terminals.

Finally executed the following command: `source ~/.zshrc`, reseted terminal again and now both `bash` and `zhs` are sync and usable.